# How to manually reset User password in Parse Server?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to implement an SMS password reset where the user is sent an OTP which they use as verification code to reset their password. After resetting and saving the user's new password, I am still unable to login with that new password, and only the old passwords work.

I have used the `setPassword` method, I have tried using `user.set('password', value)` which also does not work, and saving the user object with `user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })`. Has anyone been able to implement their own password reset flow? Or you're supposed to strictly use the inbuilt email password reset flow?

This is the specific code I used for resetting the password

```
const user = await Parse.Query
    .or(
        User.query.equalTo('resetToken', request.body.resetToken),
        User.query.equalTo('resetCode', request.body.resetToken)
    )
    .first();

if (!user){
    throw new Error('User does not exist');
}

user.setPassword(request.body.password);

// deleting resetToken && resetCode
user.unset('resetCode');
user.unset('resetToken');

await user.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
```

Comment: `setPassword` should work. There is no error message when you call the `save()` function?

Comment: Nope, no error message. Everything saves as there was no error, however I still cannot login with the new password

Comment: Do you mind to share the code you are using? It is a cloud code function, right? Could you share the whole function?

Comment: Updated the post to include the code

Comment: Could you please try with `first({useMasterKey: true})` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get what you mean. `first` as in?

Comment: In your code you have `.first();`, instead of this code, try with `.first({useMasterKey: true});`

Comment: Thank you very much! After adding that the password reset now seems to work, much appreciated!